# Why does visual studio fail to find a namespace when its assembly is already referenced in the project?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does my Visual Studio show the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Compatibility' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

when I do have Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility component already referenced under the .NET tab of Add Reference dialog box.

My .net knowledge is at very basic level. I did google the issue but couldn't find relevant solutions. Any help, hint, suggestion, links will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The project is actually an Outlook 2003 add-in in C#.

Comment: Do you also have the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly referenced?

Comment: Yes, I do have it referenced as well.

Comment: Is this really a C# question or a VB.NET question?

Comment: I did see the tags, @craftsman, but the first reference I found on MSDN to this namespace was a VB.NET library for VB6 compatibility, which prompted my question.

Comment: Obvioiusly you aren't referencing the correct assembly, or you are experiencing a namespace conflict.  What you *think* you have referenced may be incorrect; remove the reference, add it again.  Then, qualify its types with their full namespace and the global:: qualifier (e.g., global::Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support)

Comment: As it turns out, I did not reference the assembly. Viewing the "Add Reference" dialog box, I thought assemblies listed there were actually referenced. I discovered later that references were to be set from solution explorer. I know it sounds stupid, but as I mentioned I had very little knowledge of C#. Thanks for your support any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havn't shown the code that results in the error. However, the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility` assembly only contains a single namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6`. My guess is that you need to include this statement in your code

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6;
```

You state that you .NET knowledge is at a very basic level so let me try to clarify a bit.

Adding a reference to an assembly in your project allows you to instantiate types defined in that assembly and execute code belonging to these types. Simplifying things a bit you can think of the assembly name as the name of the file with the code without the DLL extension. In this case the name of the assembly is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility`.

To avoid identificer collisions .NET has the concept of a namespace. Namespaces are hierarchical in nature just as internet domain names are. The `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6` namespace is in the top-level `Microsoft` namespace with three subordinate namespaces.

To refer to a type you need to qualify it by using the namespace, e.g the fully qualified name of the `ScaleMode` enumeration is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.ScaleMode`. However, you soon get tired of doing that and most of the time you will import all the types from a namespace by putting an `using` statement at the start of your source file as shown above. Then you can simply refer to the `ScaleMode` enumeration in your code.

The confusing part here is that the assembly name is almost the same as the namespace you need.

Comment: I realized later that my question was wrong, but I am thankful for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance targeting the .NET 4 Client Framework, and does changing it to the full framework fix it?

Comment: I realized later that my question was wrong, but I am thankful for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear, but it seems that you're referencing in the code defined in another assembly and VS reports an error, even if that assembly regularly linked to main project. 
Considering that you're talking about *Outlook 2003 add-in in*, the most frequent case is that that assembly/project is not in a corresponding .NET runtime version. For example your main project has .NET Framework 4.0 version, assembly/project has 2.0 version.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I realized later that my question was wrong, but I am thankful for your answer.